# Como enviar dados de uma Activity para um Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Como vocês podem ver no código abaixo eu consigo enviar dados de um Fragment para o outro e tbm de um Fragment para a Activity mas já tentei de tudo pra enviar da Activity para o Fragment mas não estou conseguindo :(

## MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String TabFragmentB;
String TabFragmentA;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "One");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "Two");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

////Métodos que se relacionam com os fragments para trasporte de dados////

//Captura a Tag do fragment OneFragment
public void setTabFragmentA(String t){
    TabFragmentA = t;
}

//Retorna a Tag do fragment OneFragment
public String getTabFragmentA(){
    return TabFragmentA;
}


//Captura a Tag do fragment TwoFragment
public void setTabFragmentB(String t){
    TabFragmentB = t;
}

//Retorna a Tag do fragment TwoFragment
public String getTabFragmentB(){
    return TabFragmentB;
}

//Envia dados para o fragment OneFragment
public void msg_fragA(String message){

}

}
```

## OneFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

static TextView statusMessage;
static TextView txt_temporizador;
static TextView txt_limite;
static TextView txt_espera;
static TextView txt_clock;

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Infla o layout do fragment
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    String myTag = getTag();//Grava a Tag do fragment
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTabFragmentA(myTag);//Grava a Tag do fragment em uma váriavel da MainActivity

    statusMessage = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);
    txt_temporizador = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_temporizador);
    txt_limite = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_limite);
    txt_espera = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_espera);
    txt_clock = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_clock);

    return myFragmentView;
}

public void dados_update(String tp, String tl, String te, String cl) {
    //Esse metódo recebe dados do TwoFragment ao ser apertado o botão envia do mesmo

    txt_temporizador.setText(tp);
    txt_limite.setText(tl);
    txt_espera.setText(te);
    txt_clock.setText(cl);

}


}
```

## TwoFragment.java

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment {

Button btn_envia;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Infla o layout do fragment
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    String myTag = getTag();//Grava a Tag do fragment
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTabFragmentB(myTag);//Grava a Tag do fragment em uma váriavel da MainActivity

    btn_envia = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button_enviar);
    btn_envia.setOnClickListener(Envia_dados);

    return myFragmentView;
}

//Instruções que serão seguidas quando o botão enviar for clicado
View.OnClickListener Envia_dados
        = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        String TabOfFragmentA = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getTabFragmentA();//Captura a Tag do fragment OneFragment

        OneFragment fragmentA = (OneFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragmentA);

        fragmentA.dados_update("ON", "00:00:01", "00:00:02", "00:00:03");//Envia os dados para o OneFragment

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Dados enviados!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem parecido como você recebe dados via `putExtra` na `Activity`.

Antes de mais nada você precisa refatorar o método `setupViewPager`:

```
private OneFragment oneFragment;
private TwoFragment twoFragment;

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    oneFragment = new OneFragment();
    twoFragment = new TwoFragment();
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(oneFragment, "One");
    adapter.addFrag(twoFragment, "Two");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

E o momento método que envia os dados também:

```
//Envia dados para o fragment OneFragment
public void enviaMensagemParaOFragment(String message, Fragment fragment){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("CHAVE_DO_VALOR_PASSADO", message);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
}
```

E na sua `Activity` você chama o método `enviaMensagemParaOFragment` passando como parâmetro uma `string` que você quer enviar e o `Fragment` para o qual será enviado a `string`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    enviaMensagemParaOFragment("Essa é a mensagem que será enviada", oneFragment);

    ...
}
```

Já para recuperar o valor, basta alterar o método `onCreateView` do `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String message = getArguments().getString("CHAVE_DO_VALOR_PASSADO");
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    ...
}
```

Ainda se por acaso você quiser chamar o `Fragment` no evento de um click de um botão por exemplo, você pode criar uma `interface` com um método `passarInformacao`, implementar essa `interface` a partir do seu `Fragment` e chamar esse método direto da `Activity`.

#### PassadorDeInformacao.java

```
public interface PassadorDeInformacao {
    public void passaInformacao(String informacao);
}
```

#### OneFragment.java e TwoFragment.java

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements PassadorDeInformacao {

    @Override
    public void passaInformacao(String informacao) {
        // Faça o que quiser com a informação
        Log.d("OneFragment", "Recebi a informação: " + informacao);
    }

    ...
}
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...


    //Envia dados para o fragment OneFragment
    public void enviaMensagemParaOFragment(String message, PassadorDeInformacao fragment){
        fragment.passaInformacao(message);
    }

    private void onButtonClick() {
        enviaMensagemParaOFragment("minha mensagem", oneFragment);
    }

    ...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Ainda recomendo que você utilize algum dos frameworks existentes que faz todo esse trabalho para você. Entre eles tem o [Android Annotations](http://androidannotations.org/) e o [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: Deu certo, passei o dia todo quebrando a cabeça nem acredito que era uma coisa tão simples rsrs, valew ai hehe

Comment: Se deu certo pra você, você poderia marcar como resposta. Assim outras pessoas que tiveram o mesmo problema poderão ver que a sua pergunta já foi respondida :)

Comment: Desculpa é que sou novato por aqui rsrs, pronto marcado :)

Comment: Agora que fui dar uma mexida no código fui implementar o PassadorDeInformacao, tipo ele passa as informações certinho e printa no Log do fragment, porem quando vou adicionar essas informações no textView statusMessage através do setText ele dá erro. Você sabe o que pode ser? :/

Comment: Descobri o que era, os dados estavam sendo passados antes do onCreateView ser iniciado, já arrumei aqui rsrs

Answer (score -2):

Para mim serviu perfeitamente. No meu caso eu passei parâmetros de um Activity para um Fragment, e serviu para mim.

Minha activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnMercado;
Button btnChamadas;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Activity onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnMercado = findViewById(R.id.btn_mercado);
    btnChamadas = findViewById(R.id.btn_chamadas);

    ChamadasFragment chamadasFragment = new ChamadasFragment();

    btnMercado.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ConversasFragment conversasFragment = new ConversasFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("categoria", "mercado");
        conversasFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager()         //Aqui permite pegar o Fragment, criar alterar e mudar os fragments.
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_conteudo, conversasFragment)
                .commit();

    });

    btnChamadas.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_conteudo, chamadasFragment)
                //.remove(conversasFragment)
                .commit();
    });
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Activity onStart");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Activity onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Activity onPause");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Activity onStop");
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onDestroy");
 } 
}
```

E o código na minha fragment para capturar após o clique no botão "Mercado".

```
package com.tiagoribeirosantos.aulafragment.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.tiagoribeirosantos.aulafragment.R;


public class ConversasFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;

    private Button btnExecutar;
    private TextView textNome;
    private TextView textCategoria;
    private EditText editNome;

    private Bundle bundle;

    private String categoria = null;

    public ConversasFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onAttach");
    }

    //Quando a view(visualização) foi criada.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onViewCreated");
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    //Quando está criando o objeto fragment
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onCreate");



    }

    //Quando está criando a visualização do Fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onCreateView");
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversas, container, false);

        btnExecutar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_executar);
        editNome = view.findViewById(R.id.editNome);
        textNome = view.findViewById(R.id.textNome);
        textCategoria = view.findViewById(R.id.text_categoria);


        btnExecutar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            categoria = getArguments().getString("categoria");
            textCategoria.setText(categoria);

            String nomeDigitado = editNome.getText().toString();
            textNome.setText(nomeDigitado);

        });


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onPause");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onDestroyView");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.i("ciclo-vida", "Fragment onDetach");
    }
}
```