# Como faço para passar os dados da activity para seu fragment?

Tags: android

Aprendi como enviar dados de um fragment para o seu activity utilizando interface. Só que agora estou tentando fazer o inverso. Porque enviei dados para uma activity e quero que esses dados sejam de novo enviados para seus fragments.

...

Obrigado pessoal, desculpa a Demora em responder e não explicar direito, sou novo aqui e é minha primeira pergunta. Consegui, estava utilizando a biblioteca SmartTabLayout para inserir abas na activity. Ao invés de adicionar um text e a classe do fragment no FragmentPagerItemAdapter, eu adicionei apenas um FragmentPageItem já com os valores que eu queria passar para o fragment. desta forma:

```
FragmentPagerItem itemBranco = FragmentPagerItem.of("", BrancoFragment.class,
        new Bundler().putSerializable("passarTipo", tipoProduto).get());

//Configurar abas
FragmentPagerItemAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerItemAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager(),
        FragmentPagerItems.with(this)
                .add(itemBranco)
                .create()
);
```

E no fragment eu peguei os valores utilizando o onActivityCreated:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //Pegar o tipoProduto do EstoqueActivity
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    tipoProduto = (TipoProduto) bundle.getSerializable("passarTipo");

    if (tipoProduto == null){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "O tipo produto é nulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Valor tipo produto passado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Espero que possa ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema ao utilizar essa biblioteca, Abraço.

Comment: bem vindo Felipe. coloque por favor trecho do seu código para que possamos entender melhor a forma como está a tentar fazer.

Comment: Bom dia Felipe, Acesse este link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137905/como-enviar-dados-de-uma-activity-para-um-fragment/137911#137911 e veja se te atende.